# jQuery trigger key on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make something where when you are in a input you can press a button and it will fill it with a character(depending on the button) and move onto the next input.

```
$('.today').keyup(function(e) {
  if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [69, 88, 191]) === -1) { // e, x, / respectively
    e.preventDefault(); // don't print the character
    return false;
  }
  var self = $(this);
  var currentInput = self.data('number');
  var next = $(currentInput + 1);
  var previous = $(currentInput - 1);
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  var num = self.data('number') + 1;
  var nom = self.data('number') - 1;
  if(('input.today[data-number="' + num +'"]').length && keyCode === 40)
    $('input.today[data-number="' + num +'"]').focus()
  else if(('input.today[data-number="' + nom +'"]').length && keyCode === 38)
    $('input.today[data-number="' + nom +'"]').focus();
  else if(('input.today[data-number="' + num +'"]').length && self.val().length == self.attr('size')) {
    $('input.today[data-number="' + num +'"]').focus();
  }
});
```

Comment: describe your problem and the desired behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.today').keyup(function(e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [69, 88, 191]) === -1) { 
        $( this ).next().focus();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```